# Magento 2.3 & composer : update extension

Tags: magento2.3, composer

I would like to update my extension (I updated magento 2.2.6 to 2.3.1 from composer but looks like the extension also need to be updated because it's not working and it should be compatible).
Then i try :

```
composer.phar update Firebear_ImportExport
```

also tried :

```
composer.phar update Firebear/ImportExport
```

both returned

> Package "firebear_importexport" listed for update is not installed.
>   Ignoring.

also tried :

```
composer.phar require Firebear/ImportExport
```

returned :

> [InvalidArgumentException]
>                          Could not find
>   package Firebear/ImportExport.

Then I suppose I am not using the correct syntax, which syntax should I use ?

Comment: Is the extension under the vendor folder or app folder? if the app folder then composer will not be able to update that

Comment: into app/code/firebear/importexport , then how should I do ?

Comment: As Dava says, if the extension was installed manually, composer won't update it, to know if you installed it with composer, the extension files should be under vendor/, otherways they will be in app/code/

Comment: You should download the latest version from the vendor website

Comment: You would need to overwrite app/code/firebear/importexport content with the latest module version files and run bin/magento setup:upgrade. alternatively you can delete the module from app/code and run the following "composer require firebear/importexport" in your cli (without quotes) this will place the code in the vendor holder and then run setup upgrade

Comment: So i should redo the "Manual installation" for there https://firebearstudio.com/blog/improved-import-magento-2-extension-manual.html#Installation right ?

Comment: If you usually use composer for all other tasks such as upgrade i would recommend doing it using composer command but if you want to do it manually follow the manual process and it should work perfect for you

Comment: Can it be consequence on overiding module if I change it from app/code which work manually to vendor/ which work with composer ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution was to do a manual installation, it could also work with composer but anyway update is provided by the extension supplier and not automatic

Answer (score 1):

the package name is `firebear/importexport`... You can check your composer.json in an editor etc.

https://firebearstudio.com/blog/improved-import-magento-2-extension-manual.html#via_Composer

Cheers
Jan

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading the extension via composer
To upgrade the extension, navigate to your store root folder just as per instructions above and run the following commands:

```
composer update firebear/importexport
```

than

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

then

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

and

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Comment: I also did that did composer.phar update firebear/importexport report Package "firebear/importexport" listed for update is not installed. Ignoring.

Comment: try to composer require "firebear/importexport:1.0.*"  note : 1.0 mention your version.

Comment: or add manually in composer.json than run composer update

Comment: is it working ?

Comment: unfortunatly I don't have yet my login and passwork for firebeard si I have to wait for test